# Retrieve input value from js script to django view

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have created an html input in a js script this way:

```
var compte = document.createElement("input");
    compte.setAttribute("name", "compte");
```

I need to retrieve that input value into a django view. Usually, I use the name attribute of the input:

```
num=request.POST['compte']
```

In this case, it didn't work knowing the html input was created using javascript. So how do I get the value?

I'm adding below the whole code. I've actually inserted a new row containing the inputs to the table.

```
<form class="myForm" action="Plan_comptable" method='POST'
enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table id="myTable" class="gtreetable table gtreetable-fullAccess">
{% csrf_token %}

<thead><tr><th>Compte</th><th>Intitulé</th><th></th>
</tr></thead>

<tbody>
{% for el in ViewPC_query %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ el.Num }}</td>
    <td>{{ el.Intitule }}</td>

    <td width="30">
     <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-primary 
     dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Action
     <span class="caret"></span></button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a id="{{ forloop.counter }}" class="dropdown-item" 
  onclick="beforeFunction(this);" href="#">Créer avant</a></li>
  <li><a id="{{ forloop.counter }}" class="dropdown-item" 
   onclick="afterFunction(this);" href="#">Créer après</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="" href="#">Créer first child</a> 
   </li>
  <li id="actionsep"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" 
    id="actionsep">Créer last child</a></li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="Modifier_PC/{{ el.id }}">Modifier</a> 
   </li>
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="Supprimer_PC/{{ el.id 
    }}">Supprimer</a></li>
 </ul></div></td>

</tr>
          {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<script>
function beforeFunction (element) {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(element.id);

    var compte = document.createElement("input");
    compte.setAttribute("id", "idcompte");
    compte.setAttribute("name", "compte");
    compte.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

    var intitule = document.createElement("input");
    intitule.setAttribute("name", "intitule");
    intitule.setAttribute("class", "form-control");

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.setAttribute("name", "action" + element.id);
    button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle");
    button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
    var textnode1 = document.createTextNode("Action");
    var textnode2 = document.createTextNode("Enregistrer");
    var textnode3 = document.createTextNode("Annuler");
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.setAttribute("class", "caret");

    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.setAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu");

    var li1 = document.createElement("li");
    var li2 = document.createElement("li");
    var Enregistrer = document.createElement("a");
    Enregistrer.setAttribute("href", "UpdatePC_before");
    var Supprimer = document.createElement("a");
    Supprimer.setAttribute("href", "{% url 'comptes' %}");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "dropdown");

    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(compte);

    currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(intitule);

    Enregistrer.appendChild(textnode2);
    Supprimer.appendChild(textnode3);
    li1.appendChild(Enregistrer);
    li2.appendChild(Supprimer);
    ul.appendChild(li1);
    ul.appendChild(li2);
    button.appendChild(textnode1);
    button.appendChild(span);

    currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    div.setAttribute("class", "dropdown");
    div.appendChild(button);
    div.appendChild(ul);
    currentCell.appendChild(div);

}
```

Comment: But here you create an `<input>` tag *at the end of the document*, so likely *outside* the `<form>`, hence the value is indeed not submitted.

Comment: Thank you. Could you check out the code I've just added please.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are creating an input, but not appending it to the form.

`document.querySelector('form.formClassName').appendChild(compte)`

Comment: Thanks. I've actually edited my post. I already inserted a row containing cells with the inputs to the table. Is is not enough? How should I append this to the form then?